# This site does not scroll smoothly at all!

Tags: html, performance, scroll

How come? This is the site [www.jivanmulders.nl](http://www.jivanmulders.nl)

It isn't the large background image. I removed it and the scrolling experience stayed the same. It's in all browsers ...

I suspect it's the HTML ... but what and why? Thanks for any help!

Comment: How to you mean smoothly?  Are you using the mouse scrollwheel?

Comment: To link to another page, use the hyperlink button in the editor instead of adding your own html tags - these won't work.  I've edited the question for you.

Comment: I suspect it's an illusion... It looks like it actually scrolls just as smoothly as every other site to me.

Comment: May be your system needs an upgrade !!!! Just passing ideas

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post here! I'm using a touchpad and I'm on a Mac(Book Pro) so no IE only Safari, Firefox and Chrome. It does scroll badly, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** the fixed background image together with the transparency effects. Being fixed mean that the browser has to re-render the complete page every time you scroll a single pixel.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro ... and the rest of you all to look into it ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Omit the background image and all these "jivanmulders_top_A.gif" etc graphics as well. The jQuery localScroll/scrollto seems to work smoothly without them.